# FFMPEG: Images are being loaded wrong at wrong FPS

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-editing

On my video I am adding multiple overlays, 1 that will always be shown (Overlay/overlay.png) and I got a progress bar in PNGs named 0 to the last frame num.

I tried `ffmpeg -i 6875126077795372290.mp4 -i Overlay/overlay.png -i Overlay/ProgressBar/%d.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0[bg];[bg][2]overlay=0:20" output.mp4` which [@llogan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1109017/llogan) sent me and it does it all, but strangely the video is now 6 seconds longer (from 11sec to 17sec).
It seems like when it loads the images it make it have a duration of 17seconds (see full log linked below).
How should I solve this? (I got this file information using ffprobe)
Full file information: https://pastebin.com/rxkK39h7
Full ffmpeg log: https://pastebin.com/CBiusbRE

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '6875126077795372290.mp4':
  Metadata:
    minor_version   : 512
    major_brand     : isom
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:11.70, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1553 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 576x1024 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 1419 kb/s, 37 fps, 37 tbr, 18944 tbn, 74 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, png_pipe, from 'Overlay/overlay.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 576x1024, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #2, image2, from 'Overlay/ProgressBar/%d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:17.28, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #2:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 576x20, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
```

As you can see the input #2 has a duration of 17 seconds and the wrong fps of 25, how can I fix this? And yes I already tried `-framerate 37` and that didn't fix it.

Comment: What happened to the other question? I was going to address this issue you mentioned with my answer.

Comment: It got deleted because it was on the wrong website :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do -framerate before you load the image :facepalm:
`ffmpeg -i 6875126077795372290.mp4 -i Overlay/overlay.png -framerate 37 -i Overlay/ProgressBar/%d.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0[bg];[bg][2]overlay=0:20" output.mp4`

Comment: Please show the command you used. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.